# Jquery's perofrmance : more specifc or less specific?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the difference between `$('#specificID")` and `$('body .myoutterclass table tr #specificID')` in terms of performance ? (specificID is unique)

I agree that one selector can not make a visual difference but i dont know for the case when your code is full of selectors and your page is too big ..

If there is no difference in terms of performance what type of selector should i use in terms of best practices ?

Comment: Set up a JSperf so you'll know.

Comment: As the `id` as per the specification has to be unique within a document, there is no point to use a selector different from `#specificID`.

Comment: Try and avoid ID's, as they become global vars.  What I would suggest for performance is you keep a reference to parent selectors.  And then use find on those.

Comment: *"what type of selector should i use in terms of best practices ?"* in this case, just the plain ID. It's even faster than the other one.

Comment: If you using unique ID so no need to use parent selector, unless you use global css and has same id on another.

Comment: i do `$('body .myoutterclass table tr #specificID')` sometimes just to make my code more readable because when i have only IDs i may get lost on my own code, that's why i've been asking if there is a small impact on the performance

Comment: jQuery only uses the Sizzle selector engine if the browser does not support the given selector for `querySelectorAll`, so for `body .myoutterclass table tr #specificID` the results depends on the implementation of the browser.

Comment: If you care about performance on this level, skip jQuery and just use `document.querySelectorAll('#specificID')` or better `document.querySelector('#specificID')` since you already know it's 1 element, or even better, `document.getElementById('specificID')`, since you already know it's an id, and the browser doesn't need to do anything smart to parse the selector.

Comment: so there is an impact on the performance ? thats what i want to know

Comment: @GolezTrol The Browser is pretty good at parsing CSS selectors. It uses it for, well, CSS; all the time, all over the place. Don't start optimizing stuff like that. You'll loose yourself in completely pointless optimizations, and miss the parts that really have an impact on the user experience. `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` are both good options, just use the one that fits your need, wether you want the first match or all results.

Comment: @Thomas Of course it's pretty good. It's a 20 character string, so it's not hard to parse. But it's the difference between having to do so (*and* apply the actual CSS rules), or go straight to the dictionary of ids. Personally I would stick with `querySelector` and `-All`, like you suggest, but the irony here is that OP is using jQuery and is concerned about performance on this level.

Comment: @MehdiSouregi If you loose yourself with all the IDs, then turning these IDs into even longer selectors won't fix that; It adds only noise to your code. You probably do too much in your functions. Try to write functions in a way that each function does exactly one specific thing; and calls other functions to delegate the subtasks. You could also try to learn some component based framework to learn how to split your code into subtasks.

Comment: And #ID are so 90's, avoid like the plague, the global has enough to worry about without you polluting it. :)

Comment: @MehdiSouregi I'd agree on the point to avoid IDs, Keith. But not because of the global scope. The global scope is a mess in JS, everything's there. And pretty much every script runs inside a functions nowadays, because of that. No the real reason to avoid IDs, is that they are not flexible, and they don't scale.  I don't mean that they don't scale well, they don't scale at all; an ID has to be unique throughout the whole document.

Answer (score -1):

we read left to right but browser read selectors right to left, browser reads # specificID in tr then tr in table then so on.
so it gonna be huge impact on selector performance. Selectors which are inherint efficinacy are ID , Class, Type etc.

Remove extra selectors from your selection to avoid extra time. just like

## nav li a {} to #nav a {} , we already know on a inside the li it has to be inside the #nav.